# Rails アプリのCSSが効かなくなります。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, heroku

Rails4で作成したアプリをHerokuにデプロイすると、CSSが効かなくなります。

デプロイした時はCSSが効いていても、数時間後あるいは翌日にアクセスするとCSSが効かなくなっています。これはどういうことなのでしょうか？ずっとこのような事態が続いています。

また効かないといっても完全に効かないというわけではなさそうです（99.5%のCSSは効いていませんが）。キャッシュの問題なのですかね？一部背景色が適用されている部分があります。

当方プログラミングには素人でわからないことだらけなのですが、どなたか対処法をご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 問題を切り分ける必要がありますので、調査済みの内容を追記されると良いと思います。
[herokuにpushしたRailsプロジェクトのassetsが読み込まれない問題の解決方法 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/pugiemonn/items/1663ca88766ceba6a397)
[Herokuへのデプロイ時は常にproduction.rbの設定値でassets precompileされる - Qiita](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/a1833b48c3b47a955bdf)
[そろそろ開発21 CSSをHerokuにpushする話 - 緑のベジフルマイスター（野菜ソムリエ）](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yoshidaagri/20130918)

Comment: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/komiyak/20150121/1421819768
asset pipline の読み込み先がpuroductionでは変わるからではないでしょうか？